# generate calendar of a given month and year in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have been learning haskell since a week and is facing different problems. This time I have to create a calendar from a given month and year. I am almost done but the problem is that I could not start filling days from starting day.

My solution is

```
getDaysInMonth year month=(nDays,sDay) 
                          where nDays = gregorianMonthLength year month
                                sDay= digitToInt(last(showWeekDate (fromGregorian year month 01)))
year=2013
month=10
months=["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
mnth=months!!(month-1)
monthDate = getDaysInMonth year month
startAt=snd(monthDate)
totalDays = fst(monthDate)
printLine = "\n"++concat ["+---\t" | r <- [1..7]]
check x | x>totalDays=""
        | x<=totalDays=show x
genDays n m="\n "++concat[check(x)++"\t|"|x<-[n..m]]
genD 6=""
genD sP=genDays ((sP-1)*7+1) (sP*7) ++genD (sP+1)
generateCalendar=printLine++"\n "++
                        concat [[r]++"\t|" | r <- mnth]++printLine++
                        "\n Sun\t|Mon\t|Tue\t|Wed\t|Thu\t|Fri\t|Sat"++printLine++
                        genD 1
main=do
     putStrLn generateCalendar
```

Output of this program is like this

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---    
 O  |C  |T  |O  |B  |E  |R  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---    
 Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---    
 1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |
 8  |9  |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |
 15 |16 |17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |
 22 |23 |24 |25 |26 |27 |28 |
 29 |30 |31 |   |   |   |   |
```

So the problem is that October month should start from Monday. I think the implementation of the solution is little mess but how can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I think the implementation of the solution is little [messy]" - Then clean it up!  Is there any reason why you can't use custom `data` types for the months and days?  It'd be a lot cleaner and safer to not use strings.

Comment: October 2013 started on a Tuesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user5402. Finally I got working version

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate
import Data.Char
year=2014
month=2
months=["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
mnth=months!!(month-1)
monthDate = getDaysInMonth year month
startAt=snd(monthDate)
totalDays = fst(monthDate)

getDaysInMonth year month=(nDays,sDay) 
                      where nDays = gregorianMonthLength year month
                            sDay= digitToInt(last(showWeekDate (fromGregorian year month 01)))
cells = (replicate n1 "")
                          ++ [ show d | d <- [1..lastday] ]
                          ++ (replicate n2 "")
          where lastday = totalDays
                n1=(startAt-1)
                n2=(7-(totalDays-(29-startAt)))
chunksOf7 []=[]
chunksOf7 (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:rest) = [ [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] ] ++ chunksOf7 rest

pad n str = str ++ (replicate (n-(length str)) ' ')
renderCell c = pad 3 c ++ "|"
renderChunk cells =  (concat $ map renderCell cells) ++ "\n"

printLine = "\n"++concat ["+---" | r <- [1..7]]++"\n"
monthLine=concat [[r]++" |" | r <- mnth]
dayLine="Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat"
heading=concat[printLine,"Year: ",show year,printLine,monthLine,printLine,dayLine,printLine]

renderCalendarBody cells =  heading++concat (map renderChunk chunks)
  where chunks = chunksOf7 cells

main= do putStrLn $ renderCalendarBody cells
```

Answer (score 3):

A more "functional" approach to this problem would be:

1. Create a list of 35 strings, each string is either the empty string or a (stringified) number.
2. Break up the list into chunks of 7 elements each (so you get five chunks)
3. For each chunk render the elements as a row in the calendar.

For example, for the month October 2013 the list of 35 strings would be:

```
cells = [ "", "", "", "1", "2", "3", ..., "31", "", "" ]
```

The chunks can be created using this helper function:

```
chunksOf7 (a:b:c:d:e:f:g:rest) = [ [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] ] ++ chunksOf7 rest
chunksOf7 xs = xs
```

(There are better ways to define `chunksOf7`, but this will suffice.)

And to render a chunk:

```
renderChunk cells =  (concat $ map renderCell cells) ++ "\n"
renderCell c = pad 3 c ++ "|"
pad n str = str ++ (replicate (n-(length str)) ' ')
```

`pad n str` pads the string `str` with spaces on the right until the total length is `n`.
`replicate n a` creates a list of with the value `a` repeated `n` times.

And to put it all together (once you have your `cells` list):

```
renderCalendarBody cells =  concat (map renderChunk chunks)
  where chunks = chunksOf7 cells
```

Now, given a year and a month, you just have to write a function to define what `cells` is.
The cells list is going to consists of:

- some number of leading empty strings
- followed by 1 through 30 (or 31 or whatever the last day of the month is)
- followed by some number of trailing empty strings

i.e.:

```
cellsForYearAndMonth y m = (replicate n1 "")
                              ++ [ show d | d <- [1..lastday] ]
                              ++ (replicate n2 "")
  where lastday = ...
        n1 = ... number of leading empty strings ...
        n2 = ... number of trailing empty strings ...
```